# How to convert parsed html object repsonse to a valid html after removing some tags in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to parse this HTML to object, remove some tags that are not necessary and then convert it back to html and pass it down to another div and show it on the front end.

This process seems a bit redundant to me too, so please tell me if you have a better approach.

This is the jquery code;

```
var urlData = {
    token: token,
    idnlanguage: idnlng,
    domainoption: domainsData[0],
    domains: domainsData[1],
    domainsregperiod: domainsregperiod
}
$.post(url, urlData, function(data, status) {
    var xml = data,
        xmlParse = jQuery.parseHTML(xml),
        $xml = $(xmlParse),
        $header = $xml.find("#header"),
        $menu = $xml.find("#main-menu"),
        $footer = $xml.find("#footer"),
        $body = $xml.find("#main-body")

//The parsed data is an object so this line below does not work.
$("#step2").html($body)
});

<div id="step2"></div>
```

This is the response from the API

```
<html>                                      // Object index 0 after parsing

    <header>Something</header>              // Object index 1 after parsing
    
    <body id="someId">Something</body>      // Object index 2 after parsing
    
    <footer>Something</footer>              // Object index 3 after parsing
</html>
```

The response will vary from account to account so I cannot just remove an index in this object. The original response looks exactly like this except it is a lot bigger.

Now I want to pick the body with id `#someId` and push it inside `<div id="step2"></div>`

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong and do you have a better approach for this problem?

Comment: Hi , where is `main-menu` `main-body` ?

Comment: @Swati ```main-menu``` and ```main-body``` are coming from the API response

Comment: you need to paste the response here in you question